# Get to a Django field value from within the field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having an unexpected difficulty while modelling a Django app. I have a model, that consists of properties. Some properties have an external (Master Data) representation. I want to be able to get both the representation I use in my app, and the Master Data representation. My idea was to use a custom `django.db.models` field, and add a method to get that Master Data representation. Then I could use `model.field` for the 'native' representation, and `model.field.mdm_guid()` as the external representation.

However, when inheriting from a `Field`, I have not found a way to access the field's own value.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
class MdmField(TextField):
    def __init__(self, *kargs, **kwargs):
        self.mdm_type = kwargs.pop('mdm_type', None)

    def mdm_guid(self, value):
        return masterdata[self.mdm_type].get(value, 0)
```

The `masterdata` dictionary contains these external representations, but that is not important for this question.

I'm bothered with the need to pass in the value of the field! Can I not access the value of the field from within the field itself? Is there no way to get to the model from the field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this section of the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#what-does-a-field-class-do):

> It’s important to realize that a Django field class is not what is stored in your model attributes. The model attributes contain normal Python objects. The field classes you define in a model are actually stored in the `Meta` class when the model class is created (the precise details of how this is done are unimportant here). This is because the field classes aren’t necessary when you’re just creating and modifying attributes. Instead, they provide the machinery for converting between the attribute value and what is stored in the database or sent to the serializer.

That's why the custom field requires you to pass in a value - it's just doing conversions, it's not part of your model instance.

Instead you can just define a plain old Python class that has your `mdm_guid()` method, and have your custom field take and return that. For an example, see the distinction between the `Hand` class and the `HandField` class in the documentation referenced above.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me!